# Enable GZIP on NGINX server for Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, nginx

I checked my configuration file /etc/nginx/ngnix.conf and not found any issue. still not able to see the css and javascript Gzip Compression. My NGINX.conf entries are as below-

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/js text/xml text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml application/xml+rss;
gzip_vary on;
```

It is not compressing any css or js file included on my server. The external jquery and css font is getting compressed. Is there anything that am doing wrong? Do I have to change anything in some other setting file as well?

Comment: Too little information (for example you haven't included the configuration section on static files) and this question is probably better off on server fault.

Comment: how do i include configration secion on static files?